# Integrability of $2\pi$-periodic function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, periodic-functions, riemann-integration

I WTS that if $f$ is periodic and Riemann integrable on $[-\pi, \pi]$, then $f$ is integrable on any closed interval and for every real number $x,$ we have $\int_{x-\pi}^{x+\pi}f = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f$.

I know that the quickest proof of this comes from the change-of-variable formula.

But since I haven't seen the proof for change-of-variables without the assumption that $f$ is continuous,  I want to prove the above statement without this formula.

The hint I have is to use the sequential criterion for integrability, namely: $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ if and only if there is a sequence of partitions $(P_n)$ of $[a,b]$ such that $\lim U(f, P_n)-L(f, P_n) =0$, in which case $\lim U(f, P_n)=\lim L(f, P_n)=\int_{a}^{b}f$.

I don't see how to apply this, however.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Write the sum of a partition I'd try to "move" every rectangle $x$, and the periodic condition $f \left({x}\right) = f \left({x+L}\right)$.

Comment: @RafaBudría I've tried that. But I've had no luck working out the details. Would you mind showing me how it's done? This is just for an exam review, not homework

Comment: Not done by me, but there is the idea in two versions as answers.

Comment: @RafaBudria What would the sequence look like? It's not in the answers given.

Comment: Oh, one answer has been deleted. It seemed ok and little more detailed.

Comment: @RafaBudría Say I have a partition $P=\{y_1, \ldots, y_n\}$ of $\{-\pi, \pi\}$. Then say I have the partition $Q=\{y_1 +x, \ldots, y_n+x\}$ of the new interval. Are the upper sums of $f$  under these partitions equal? If so, is it because of periodicity?

Comment: Yes. To $P=\{y_1, \ldots, y_n\}$ corresponds $\{f(y_1),\dots,f(y_n)\}$ used to form the rectangles and then the sums. You integrate now between $-\pi+x$ and $\pi+x$, so, exists $f(y_1)=f(y_i)$ for some $i$ such that $y_1+2\pi k =y_i$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$. So, to $\{y_i,\dots,y_n,y_1\dots,y_{i-1}\}$ corresponds $\{f(y_1),\dots,f(y_n\}$ too.

Comment: The reasoning have to be "fine tuned" because $y_i$ is at most "the nearest of y's" to $y_1+2\pi k$ for the chosen displacement $x$, This can be fixed showing that the difference vanishes in the limit for both the upper sum and the lower sum.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic, it should be clear $f$ is Riemann integrable (RI) on every $[\pi,3\pi], [3\pi,5\pi],\dots$ because the upper minus lower sums on each such interval correspond exactly to those on $[-\pi,\pi],$ where we know $f$ is RI. Same thing for $[-3\pi,-\pi], [-5\pi,-3\pi], \dots$

Recall two easily proved results: i) if $f$ is RI on both $[a,b]$ and $[b,c],$ then $f$ is RI on $[a,c];$ ii) if $f$ is RI on $[a,b]$ and $a\le a'<b'\le b,$ then $f$ is RI on $[a',b'].$ From this and the above it follows that $f$ is RI on any closed bounded interval.

Comment: Ok, but how would I show that the integral doesn't change when you add an arbitrary value to endpoints?

Comment: The idea is that the rectangles in the each of both sums, so say, rearrange: You "delete" some of them by the left, but they all appear by the right.